# Ionic 6 - (android and ios) keyboard pushes and squishes content up

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, keyboard

I've searched a lot about this question but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

So basically when I click on a input in my app the keyboard displaying causes my content to go up and get squished, does anyone know how to fix this issue? I'm looking for something like when the keyboard shows up the content stays behind the keyboard and stays like scrollable or something like that.

Here are some images of what happens:

[before keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cQv.png)
[after keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7vPA.png)